# Rename file to creation time (batch file only)

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

Not sure this is possible with only a batch file.

I have a file named BaseFile.7z location is E:\Backup\C Drive Zip\BaseFile.7z

Is it possible to create a batch command that renames the file with its creation date? For example BaseFile - 02-19-2015.7z

I currently have a command that renames the file with the current date which I pasted below for reference, but thats not exactly what I'm looking for. I need creation date.

```
RENAME "E:\Backup\C Drive Zip\Jaipur.txt" "BaseFile - %date:/=-%.txt"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "filename=U:\sourcedir\zzz.zzz"
IF NOT EXIST "%filename%" ECHO "%filename%" NOT found&GOTO :eof
SET "datepart="
FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=/-:" %%a IN ('dir /tc "%filename%"') DO IF "%%c" neq "" SET "datepart=%%a-%%b-%%c"
FOR /f %%a IN ("%filename%") DO FOR /f %%d IN ("%datepart%") DO ECHO(REN "%%a" - "%%~na %%d%%~xa"
GOTO :EOF
```

The required REN command is merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the command is correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the file.

Note that there is general sloppiness in the use of date-references. There are three dates on each file - actual create date (use /tc), last access (/ta) and last-written (/tw).

The process locates the file, then reads a `dir` listing with the appropriate date selected. The only or last line in the listing that will contain a third non-empty token is the date/time of the file in question, so `datepart` will acquire `yyyy-mm-dd hh`

the `for/f %%a` then applies the full filename to `%%a` ready for partitionig into its components and the `for/f %%d` assigns the first token from `datepart` (ie up to the space) into %%d.

Bang the components together, and the resut is reported...